# Facebook Graph Api : Get info about fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for informations about this fanpage : https://www.facebook.com/gabrielmedinasurf

when I call the graph API (v1.0) at https://graph.facebook.com/gabrielmedinasurf
I get nothing but a RTFM message :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

This process was supported a month ago. Does anyone had to face the same problem ?

I know the page ID : 206550296052269

but calling the API with it gave me the same result (https://graph.facebook.com/206550296052269)

Note : The v1.0 should be available until April 30, 2015 (source : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Any help is welcome

**NOTE :** On this older post from SO, the process seems to work : [Get Facebook fan page ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134996/3484498)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use an Access Token for any Graph API call. That being said, the Page may be restricted by age or location, an App Access Token is not good enough in that case. You can only use a User Access Token or Page Access Token. I just tried with a User Token and it worked for that Page.

If you don´t know how to handle the different Access Tokens, take a look at the following links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: It seems right (Strange restriction, the page belong to a pro surfer !). Thanks !